# Recursive folders list in Office 365 unified API

Tags: office365, office365api

I am trying to get list of mail folders using Microsoft Graph unified API. By default it returns 1st level of folders only(no child folder). so I used $expand=childFolders to get child folders too. again it returned 1st & 2nd level of folders but not 3rd and 4th level. 
I tried OData $levels to get folders upto 5th level but it is not returning. 
I don't know $levels is supported by unified API or not because its not found anywhere in unified API's website.

has anyone idea how I can get all folders in single request?

I used this url :

> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders?$top=50&$expand=childFolders($levels=5)

Answer (score 0):

Par - Getting a list of ALL mail folders isn't currently possible in v1.0 with a single request. You have to get a list of folders, and iterate through the list, to get all children, and get their children and so on.  We do support this in Beta and here is an example:

`GET http://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/mailfolders?$top=50`

We don't yet have an ETA for when this capability will be available in a production version.

Comment: I agree with you. I raised question to get all level or upto 5 level at once to prevent multiple request. 
I am able to get upto second level using https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders?$top=50&$expand=childFolders
There is no proper documentation available for Microsoft Graph API so i was wondering that $levels works or not.